# Глобальный доступ к переменной

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такой код:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    var height = $(this).css('height');
    $(this).stop().animate({height: 100}, 75);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({height: height}, 150, 'linear');
});
```

Перед тем, как начать анимацию, где-то надо сохранить текущий параметр высоты элемента. Я, понимаю, что глобальная переменная подходит в качестве решения, но, мне кажется, что это не очень правильно, не очень эстетично. Как правильно сохранить это значение?

ЗЫ: пример исключительно ради демонстрации, я знаю о том, что можно сделать через глобальную переменную, через '+='.

Comment: Пробовали [css3 transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)? [Ваш пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ks29T/).

Comment: он умеет работать с цветами?

Comment: да, умеет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если глобальные переменные так печалят, можно задействовать например data().

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    $this
        .data("original_height",$this.height())
        .stop()
        .animate({height: 100}, 75)
}, function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    $this
        .stop()
        .animate({height:$this.data("original_height")}, 150, 'linear')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

например, для сохранения предыдущего значения я использую атрибут "data-"

```
$('<a href="#"></a>').data('param1','value')

<a href="#" data-param1="value"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно заново ловить состояние высоты.

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    var height = $(this).css('height');
    $(this).stop().animate({height: 100}, 1500);
    console.log("Сжимаем c "+height);
}, function() {
    var height = $(this).css('height');
    $(this).stop().animate({height: height}, 0, 'linear');
    console.log("Состояние "+height);
});
```

Comment: если отлавливать в hendlerOut функции, то параметр будет уже измененным